# Which design pattern is appropriate to use?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I really did not want to post this question, but I have no ideas for few days already. In my university I was given task to use design patterns to "solve" some tasks.

Here is task I'm stuck on (translation):

> The kiosk has 2 vending machines with cocktails. One contains several alcoholic cocktails, the other one - their non-alcoholic alternatives. Depending on the age of buyer dispense alcoholic or non-alcoholic cocktail.

I've already made 2 solutions, but none of them has design patterns. I was thinking about creational patterns, but from examples of its use I don't think that it is good choice. Also thought about strategy, mediator, chain of responsibility, facade and bridge, but as it seemed to me it is doesn't fit here too.

Also, additional problem is I started learning patterns only 2 weeks ago, so still pretty bad at using them.

I don't even care already about quality of code, I just want to finish this task with appropriate pattern and continue my normal studying without forcing me to use any kind of things without real need in them.

What design pattern can I use in my situation?

Here is my last attempt

```
public class Kiosk
{
    private readonly Dispenser _alcoholicDispenser = new Dispenser(), _nonAlcoholicDispenser = new Dispenser();

    public void AddCocktail(string name, CocktailRecipe alcoholicRecipe, CocktailRecipe nonAlcoholicRecipe)
    {
        _alcoholicDispenser.AddCocktail(new Cocktail(name, true, alcoholicRecipe));
        _nonAlcoholicDispenser.AddCocktail(new Cocktail(name, false, nonAlcoholicRecipe));
    }

    public bool RemoveCocktail(string name)
    {
        if (!_alcoholicDispenser.RemoveCocktail(name)) 
            return false;

        _nonAlcoholicDispenser.RemoveCocktail(name);
        return true;
    }

    public Cocktail GetCocktail(Person person, string cocktailName)
    {
        if (person.Age < 18) 
            return _nonAlcoholicDispenser.Dispence(cocktailName);
        else 
            return _alcoholicDispenser.Dispence(cocktailName);
    }
}

public class Dispenser
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Cocktail> _cocktails = new Dictionary<string, Cocktail>();

    public void AddCocktail(Cocktail cocktail)
    {
        _cocktails.Add(cocktail.Name, cocktail);
    }

    public bool RemoveCocktail(string cocktailName)
    {
        return _cocktails.Remove(cocktailName);
    }

    public Cocktail Dispence(string cocktailName)
    {
        return _cocktails[cocktailName];
    }
}

public class Cocktail
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Alcoholic { get; set; }
    public CocktailRecipe Recipe { get; set; }

    public Cocktail(string name, bool alcoholic, CocktailRecipe recipe)
    {
        Name = name;
        Alcoholic = alcoholic;
        Recipe = recipe;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string res = "Name:" + Name + "(" + (Alcoholic ? "alcoholic" : "non-alcoholic") + ")";
        return res;
    }
}

public class CocktailRecipe
{
    public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredient
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Volume { get; set; }

    public Ingredient(string name, double volume)
    {
        Name = name;
        Volume = volume;
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var kiosk = new Kiosk();

        kiosk.AddCocktail("Mojito", new CocktailRecipe(), new CocktailRecipe());

        var majorPerson = new Person("Tom", 20);
        var minorPerson = new Person("Jimmy", 17);

        Console.WriteLine(kiosk.GetCocktail(majorPerson, "Mojito"));
        Console.WriteLine(kiosk.GetCocktail(minorPerson, "Mojito"));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try a `Factory` pattern, perhaps with a `CocktailDispenserFactory` that takes an age as a parameter...it will return a `ICocktailDispenser` which, by the factory, will be instantiated appropriately based on age. You would have 2 implementations of `ICocktailDispenser`, Alcoholic and Nonalcholic. Either way, good luck with the assignment and don't stress too hard at 2 weeks in.

Comment: there are multiple design patterns that can be used, but it depends on the way you approach the problem. If it is one step that alters the behavior at one stage then it is Strategy pattern, if you alter the object at the time of creation then it is Factory pattern. so it depends on your approach

Comment: @SimonWilson the problem with factory pattern is creating new dispenser each time I want to get a cocktail, not really nice way in my opinion. Also I need to have some kind of  place where both cocktail "recipes" will be held and can be added or removed.

Comment: @Hoshani why I don't like strategy here because every time person wants to get a cocktail program will need to assign new strategy. If we are creating it each time it looks pretty  bad in terms of performance. If it is already created then is just unnecessary thing to do because only method where strategy will be used is Dispense so you can just directly use what you need.

Comment: "Bad in terms of performance" - I expect even a mediocre laptop from 10 years ago will have created a few million cocktail dispensers by the time the rest of the mechanism has finished dispensing the actual liquid of the first one. Keep a sense of perspective

Comment: "Bad in terms of performance" that is why they are called design patterns!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the use of `Factory Method` pattern. Bear in mind that in GoF there is not Factory pattern, only Factory Method and Abstract Factory patterns.

I will not give you the solution, but I will provide the details here.

1. In you Kiosk item you need to create two **private** `Dispenser` objects (this is your abstract `Creator`)
2. Create an `AlchoholicDispenser` as a concrete `Creator` and a `NonAlchoholicDispenser` as your other concrete  `Creator`. Later on, you might also create the `ChocolateDispenser` and many others.
3. Inside your kiosk, create an `if/else` clause, and depending on the requester choose the `Dispenser` object of your choice.

Later on, you might want to Create a `Dictionary<ItemType, Dispenser>` create the serve function as such: `kiosk.Serve(ItemType.NonAlchoholic)`

The code would look like

```
public Beverage Serve(ItemType type) {
    dispenserDict[type].CreateItem();
}
```